# Jetty - connection pool for different contexts and database, but same lookup code

Tags: java, jetty, jndi, connection-pooling

I'm trying to configure the connection pool 2 web applications using .xml context descriptor for 2 separate context paths and databases, but with the same logical code.
The problem is that when using JNDI to lookup the datasource, the resources are overridden when jetty loads the context, and the apps end up using the same database. Here is my configuration and code:

Configuration for MyApp1.xml:

```
<New id="myDataBase" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
   <Arg></Arg>
   <Arg>jdbc/myDataBase</Arg>
   <Arg>
      <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
         <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://host:3306/mydb</Set>
         <Set name="User">...</Set>
         <Set name="Password">...</Set>
      </New>
   </Arg>
  </New>
```

Configuration for MyApp2.xml

```
  <New id="myDataBase" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
   <Arg></Arg>
   <Arg>jdbc/myDataBase</Arg>
   <Arg>
      <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
         <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://host:3306/mydb-test2</Set>
         <Set name="User">...</Set>
         <Set name="Password">...</Set>
      </New>
   </Arg>
  </New>
```

Code used by the apps:

```
public class MyDb {
...

static {
  try {
    datasource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/myDataBase");

  } catch (NamingException e) {
    // ...
  }
...

}
```

So, jetty loads context for MyApp1.xml, then MyApp2.xml. When I try to access the apps, they both use the same database: mydb-test2.

How can I properly resolve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I have tried adding the argument  in the configuration but it is not working; it is strange that now the contexts both use the first configured database: mydb

This is the xml for each app:

```
<Configure id='wac1' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
...

  <New id="myDataBase" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
       <Arg><Ref refid='wac1'/></Arg>
       <Arg>jdbc/myDataBase</Arg>
       <Arg>
          <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
             <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://host:3306/mydb</Set>
             <Set name="User">...</Set>
             <Set name="Password">...</Set>
          </New>
       </Arg>
      </New>

...




<Configure id='wac2' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
...

  <New id="myDataBase" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
       <Arg><Ref refid='wac2'/></Arg>
       <Arg>jdbc/myDataBase</Arg>
       <Arg>
          <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
             <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://host:3306/mydb-test2</Set>
             <Set name="User">...</Set>
             <Set name="Password">...</Set>
          </New>
       </Arg>
      </New>

...
```

What am I missing? Do I have to change the code (way in which I make the lookup)?

I've tried

```
datasource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataBase");
```

but I get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException - probably because I dont use env variables, but I don't think I need that, just per context scope lookup)

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, so I was actually missing a web.xml config which solved the issue (see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi-configuration.html#configuring-datasources)

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/HugaDataBase</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [scope](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-jetty-jndi.html#jndi-name-scope) for the JNDI entries. Instead of the empty first argument, you should have something like this:`<Arg><Ref refid='myapp'/></Arg>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't seam to make it work. I've read the docs regarding the link and it should work, but I still can't get the apps to connect to different databases. I've edited my post and added some more data.

Comment: I think you actually do need to add a resource-ref to your web.xml. Have you tried that? Then the java:comp/env seems right and is the one you should use.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that a few hours later and it worked, I forgot to post. This linked helped: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi-configuration.html#configuring-datasources